# Convert List double array to List Double

Tags: c#, json

I have some json format using that i created a class with properties.

Below is my json data format:

```html
       [{
            coordinates: [-74, 40.7],
            values: [22.4, 23.2, 21.5, 20.6,12.3],
        },
        {
            coordinates: [-77, 38.90],
            values: [13.4, 18.2, 24.5, 10.6, 16.3],
        },
        {
            coordinates: [-87, 41.88],
            values: [39.3, 28.8, 10.4, 20.0, 0],
        }]
```

Below is my class created from json data:

```
public class MapDataList
{
    public List<double> coordinates { get; set; }
    public List<double> values { get; set; }
}
```

and i have to set value for coordinates and values properties like below:

coordinates: [-74, 40.7],
 values: [22.4, 23.2, 21.5, 20.6,12.3],

So that this value i can use in my map chart.

I have created one method and tried something in below:

```
public List<MapDataList> CreateMapData()
{
    List<MapDataList> lstMapData = new List<MapDataList>();
    MapDataList mdl = new MapDataList();
    List<double[]> lb1=new List<double[]>();
    double[] coordinateItem1 = {-74, 40.7};
    lb1.Add(coordinateItem1);
    return lstMapData;
}
```

But question here is i have to set lb1 object data to lstMapData object.

Comment: So you have two arrays (coordinates and value) and you want to add both to your object. Are they a json string or C# arrays?

Comment: I'm no sure what you're trying to do. What it the expected input and output?

Comment: `return new List<MapDataList> { new MapDataList { coordinates = new List<double> {-74, 40.7 } } };`

Comment: @RufusL, Your solution works but i need this new List<double>{-74, 40.7} to a object which i can pass here directly instead of passing values.

Comment: Ok, then perhaps you should update your question with the method signature that you want. Doesn't aloisdg's answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm updating this answer, but you should know: it's still NOT clear what you are trying to do.

I made a new fiddle. What this does is:

1. Create a LIST of `MapDataList` out of the JSON you provided.
2. Create an IEnumerable of doubles for coordinates and create an IEnumerable of doubles for values.

I did that last thing because the title of your question seems to indicate you need a list of doubles, while having a list of double-array's.

If this is NOT what you need, please be MORE CLEAR!

Code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = "[{ coordinates: [-74, 40.7], values: [22.4, 23.2, 21.5, 20.6,12.3], }, { coordinates: [-77, 38.90], values: [13.4, 18.2, 24.5, 10.6, 16.3], }, { coordinates: [-87, 41.88], values: [39.3, 28.8, 10.4, 20.0, 0], }]";

        var mapDataLists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MapDataList>>(json);

        var coordinates = mapDataLists.SelectMany(d => d.coordinates);
        var values = mapDataLists.SelectMany(d => d.values);

        Console.WriteLine("Coordinates");
        foreach(var d in coordinates){
            Console.WriteLine(d);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Values");
        foreach(var d in coordinates){
            Console.WriteLine(d);
        }
    }
}

public class MapDataList
{
    public List<double> coordinates { get; set; }
    public List<double> values { get; set; }
}
```

Please see this fiddle and TRY it yourself:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/C48r6T

Comment: I updated my question where i added json format which i converted to class using Json2CSharp converter online.

Comment: I have mentioned above json file to make you to ensure that using that format i got the class MapDataList. As you updated above taking format from json data is not correct. This is just for testing purpose i used json data. But actual data will represent from database only.

Comment: Your question just gets more confusing.

Comment: Great! Good luck on the project.

Answer (score 0):

Object Initializer is a helpful notion.

> Object initializers let you assign values to any accessible fields or properties of an object at creation time without having to invoke a constructor followed by lines of assignment statements.

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)

- Use the MapDataList Object Initializer to create it
- Use the List Object Initializer to wrap mdl into the new list

Also, the easiest way to convert an array (or any collection) to a list is to use the `.ToList()` method from `System.Linq;`

Code:

```
public static List<MapDataList> CreateMapData(double[] coordinates, double[] values )
{
    MapDataList mdl = new MapDataList
    {
        Coordinates = coordinates.ToList(),
        Values = values.ToList()
    };
    return new List<MapDataList> { mdl };
}
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oaAHnz)

Note that you could even remove mdl and write

```
public static List<MapDataList> CreateMapData(double[] coordinates, double[] values )
{
    return new List<MapDataList> { new MapDataList
    {
        Coordinates = coordinates.ToList(),
        Values = values.ToList()
    }};
}
```